# Unit Test EntityFrameworkCore IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

How do I unit test EntityFrameworkCore.IEntityTypeConfiguration?

I want to make sure that my configuration is unit tested for several reasons:

1. avoid the burden of creating integration tests which depends more on the data setup
2. using a feature flag framework, I want to make sure that I map to different views and tables depending on the status of the flag
3. I use several custom converters which I must make sure are used
4. simply I want clear self contained tests to fail in case someone changes something that shouldn't, at that point they must intentionally remove a test

I was unable to find an answer to this question, so I had to dig it out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var sut = new MyEntityTypeConfiguration();    
var entityType = new EntityType("MyEntityName", typeof(MyEntityName), new Model(), false, ConfigurationSource.Convention);                
var builder = new EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntityName>(entityType);
    
sut.Configure(builder);
    
// Metadata will contain all the set configurations
var meta = builder.Metadata;
var properties = builder.Metadata.GetDeclaredProperties();
var viewName = builder.Metadata.GetViewName();

[..]
```

I would recommend to use a method like this in your testing libraries to simplify the setup

```cs
private static EntityTypeBuilder<T> GetEntityBuilder<T>() where T : class
{
#pragma warning disable EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
    var entityType = new EntityType(typeof(T).Name, typeof(T), new Model(), false, ConfigurationSource.Convention);

    var builder = new EntityTypeBuilder<T>(entityType);
    return builder;
#pragma warning restore EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
}
```

which you would use in this way:

```cs
var sut = new MyEntityTypeConfiguration();
var builder = GetEntityBuilder<MyEntity>();

sut.Configure(builder);

var meta = builder.Metadata;
var properties = builder.Metadata.GetDeclaredProperties();
var viewName = builder.Metadata.GetViewName();
```

Once the configure method is called, the builder Metadata property will contain all the details necessary for the correct EF configuration which are accessible and on which you can perform any desired assertion.

Comment: This could be a great thread with some more explanation about what you're doing.

Comment: @anastaciu I am not sure what else should be written down to simplify the understanding.
I show how to create the EntityType and call the Configure method, which is what happens in EF.
The Metadata, as it is written in the response, contains all the details about the Entity setup, for example properties, keys, types, relationships and so on.
So using the metadata you can create assertions depending on your need. For example I can create an assertion to check that I am binding to the View1, that I have the property "name".
If you have a specific doubt I can try to make it clearer.

Comment: Mainly I would explain what I'm doing with the code, even if with comments, the first snippet as no explanation at all, and the rest you could explain further, I'll still upvote, though, despite not having tested it yet. Looks good. You have 200+ views, this should have at least 10 upvotes.